# diplomacy game judge algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I am writing a server for playing the great *diplomacy* game online. **Does anyone know an algorithm for the judge, that will calculate all moves/supports/convoys on the map at the end at each round?**

For implementing the protocol I use twisted, for db-access django

Comment: Now *that* is a hairy set of calculations!

Comment: Is the "twisted" tag perhaps meant to lend greater meaning in the "that's twisted" sense? Good luck!

Comment: ...does anyone know an algorithm for what stocks I should sell each day?

Comment: I think maybe Jason misread your question and thought you were asking for an AI type algorithm that would generate moves etc. :)

Comment: sarcasm revoked, apologies. It would be helpful if you posted a link to the specific algorithm in question. It sounded to me like an under-specified set of requirements.

Comment: er, a link to the specific game (not algorithm) in question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  [DPjudge Adjudication Algorithm](http://www.floc.net/dpjudge/?page=Algorithm).  Also see the DPJudge FAQ answer to the [question about convoy paradoxes](http://www.floc.net/dpjudge/?page=Questions).

A check the [njudge](http://www.njudge.org/) page that links to source code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Seems to be what I was looking for!

Comment: new [DPjudge Adjudication Algorithm](http://uk.diplom.org/?page=Algorithm) link

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to look into the [DAIDE](http://www.daide.org.uk/index.xml) project. They have a full comm protocol for create dip bot players against special servers. It's not open source (unfortunately) but there is a small community who use it to play real-time Dip games when 7 humans aren't available to play.